# How to get ViewModel attached to activity using ViewModelProvider inside Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

As We all know `ViewModelProviders` are Deprecated i am trying to remove the deprecated code moving to `ViewModelProvider`.

So basically i have one ViewModel(no argument's) attached to the activity and all the fragment's access the same instance for the app state.

I want to know in my activity/fragment how can i get the instance of the ViewModel attached to the Activity.

#### Activity:

```
val weatherViewModelFactory = WeatherViewModelFactory()
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(viewModelStore, weatherViewModelFactory).get(WeatherViewModel::class.java)
```

#### Fragment:

```
val weatherViewModelFactory = WeatherViewModelFactory()
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(activity!!.viewModelStore, weatherViewModelFactory).get(WeatherViewModel::class.java)
```

#### WeatherViewModelFactory:

```
//use less in my case 
class WeatherViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor().newInstance()
    }
}
```

#### Gradle Dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
```

Main issue you must have noticed is that i am forced to create `WeatherViewModelFactory` each and every time, even when i have to get a instance for the fragment.

---

---

What i have noticed is that in `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-rc02` they have introduces a Constructor.

> ```
> public ViewModelProvider(@NonNull ViewModelStoreOwner owner) {
> ```

Which can solve my problem but i don't want to move to that version.I must be missing something in `2.1.0`